# Empty message in treepanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, treepanel

Is there a way to add empty Text config to tree panel in EXT?

Here is some sample Fiddler i found in web which meets my use case
[Sampe Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/mch)

In this user allowed to search tree if the given string matches then filtered tree will be displayed.

My case is assume when no node matches requirement , How to show to end user saying **"No Node is found"**

Comment: How exactly do you want to show the message? Maybe you might use a [toast](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.window.Toast.html) for this?

Comment: i am using Ext Js version 3,2,1, not possible

Answer (score 1):

There is an emptyText config that can be used.
Here is that same fiddle you referenced, updated to include

```
emptyText: 'No Node is found',
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1num

See also:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#cfg-emptyText

You mentioned in a comment above that you are using Ext version 3.  In that case see:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridView-cfg-emptyText

[image: here is a view of the fiddle showing the emptyText value]

Comment: thanks john, by the way i am working on EXT Version 3.4 can you provide some help on this